# Unable to catch ServiceController.Start() exceptions in calling thread

Tags: c#, windows-services, servicecontroller

How can i catch the exception that occurs when starting a windows service. I am unable to get the exception here in my below code even though i am throwing exception in the Onstart() method of the service.

```
public class InterOpIntegrationWinService : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
    } 
}
```

Calling thread code

```
try
{
    using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController())
    {
        controller.ServiceName = objServiceConfig.ServiceName;
        controller.Start();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        //controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
        //controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException))
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Error with starting service : " + LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException);
        //    LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException = string.Empty;
        //}
    }
}
catch (System.InvalidOperationException InvOpExcep)
{
    DisplayError(InvOpExcep.Message);
    LogUtilities.DisplayMessage("Failed to start service. " + LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException, InvOpExcep);
    LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException = string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DisplayError(ex.Message);
    LogUtilities.DisplayMessage("Failed to start service. " + LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException, ex);
    LogUtilities.ServiceOnStartException = string.Empty;
}
```

i check for application license in the onstart() method and throws a licensing error if it fails. i want this to shared to my calling thread so i could show the message in a DialogBox. Any ideas of how to do this if i cannot handle the exceptions in my calling process.

Comment: How do you know you are not catching it?

Comment: After controller.start() , it doesn't go into the exception block , neither in the invalidOperationException nor the exception block

Comment: Exceptions only "exist" within a single process - there's no concept of catching exceptions that happen inside of other processes - and starting a service starts a new process.

Comment: i check for application license in the onstart() method and throws a licensing error if it fails. i want this to shared to my calling thread so i could show the message in a DialogBox. Any ideas.

Comment: The thread that is starting the service (it probably isn't a good idea to think of it as the "calling thread" since you're actually launching a separate process) could monitor the service status to see whether it starts successfully or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your service into (at least) two components - a component that deals with [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) in some form (e.g. Remoting, WCF endpoint, REST service, etc) and (one or more) components that do its actual job.

If the licensing check fails, don't start the other components - but do still start the component that offers IPC. After starting your service (which should now always at least start), you forms-based application can connect to the service and (through whatever means you want) determine that the service is currently refusing to provide any functionality due to a failed licensing check.